# how to give space between bar and it's label?

Tags: rgraph

I am using RGraph in Angular7 and i want to apply space between bar and it's label

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the style of the chart you might need to upgrade and then you could add the property yaxisLabelsOffsetx to your configuration. Here's an example:

```
new RGraph.HBar({
    id:'cvs',
    data: [8,4,6,3],
    options: {
        marginInner: 10,
        variant: '3d',
        xaxis: false,
        yaxis: false,
        labelsAbove: true,
        labelsAboveOffsetx: 10,
        yaxisLabels: ['Jimmy','James','Tabatha','Richard']
    }
}).draw();
```

And a codepen of the example is here:

https://codepen.io/rgraph/pen/mdReQmm

Comment: HI Richard, currently i am using 5.26 do i need to update version.

Comment: No you should be OK with that version.